# Ink Html Framework responsive menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there are no examples or documentation on how to make a responsive menu using SAPO's Ink HTML5 framework.  How do you create such responsive menu (one with hamburger icon) using Ink?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Check their nav doc: http://ink.sapo.pt/ui-elements/navigation/ Or just try to find it out from the source of their main page. There's a hamburger icon on the left when the window is small enough